# JSON POST Data via HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, rest, http, url

I am trying to make a request to my RESTful API using Android and `HttpURLConnection`. The data must be sent in the JSON format via POST data.

Here is my code:

```
JSONObject check_request = new JSONObject();
check_request.put("username", username);

JSONObject request = BuildRequest(check_request, "username_check", false);
Log.i("DEBUG", request.toString());
// DEBUG OUTPUT: {"timestamp":1526900318,"request":{"username":"blubberfucken","type":"username_check"}}

URL request_url = new URL(apiURL);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)request_url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "TheGameApp");
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);

OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
os.write(request.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.flush();


InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

String result = "";

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF8"));
String str;
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    result += str;
}

Log.i("DEBUG", result);

//JSONObject result_json = new JSONObject(result);
os.close();
in.close();
connection.disconnect();
```

You can see the Debug output as a Comment. The Problem is that the API does not receive any POST data. I have used PHPs `var_dump` to dump `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` which both are empty arrays.

What am I missing here?

As the question popped up if the API work. This cURL command works fine with the correct result (it is the same JSON data as the debugger printed):

```
curl -d '{"timestamp":1526900318,"request":{"username":"blubberfucken","type":"username_check"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost/v1/api.php
```

Comment: Is your api working fine? are you sending appropriate data? check api with postman.

Comment: My API is working. Via CURL everything checks out fine. Added the CURL example in the post at the bottom.

Comment: @AswinPAshok  if you are using ok http then no need to read from page nad all those thing what is wrong with i sugg with ok http

Comment: @MehulTank I do not want to use ok http. Please stop recommending it.

Comment: https://www.studytutorial.in/android-httpurlconnection-post-and-get-request-tutorial May be you can find something there.

Comment: It seems really to be a problem in my API. When using `application/json` instead of `application/json; charset=UTF-8` it works... Yes. switched needle and haystack in PHP :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness: The example above is working. The solution to the problem was pa part in PHP on the server side, where I checked the content type and used strpos to search for `application/json` in `$_SERVER['CONTENT-TYPE']` and switched the `needle` and `haystack` (thus searching for `application/json; charset=UTF8` in the string `application/json` instead of the other way around).